# Hadoop 2.6.1 Single Node Set up : Data Node is not up

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I tried to set up Hadoop 2.6.1 based on instructions from [here](http://pingax.com/install-hadoop2-6-0-on-ubuntu/)

But my data node is not up. When I do JPS , I get only the below process

```
▶ jps
8406 ResourceManager
7744 NameNode
8527 NodeManager
8074 SecondaryNameNode
9121 Jps
```

DataNode Log:

```
2015-10-07 13:02:24,144 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /home/vinod/.hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode : 
EPERM: Operation not permitted
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2462)
2015-10-07 13:02:24,147 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/home/vinod/.hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode/" 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2462)
2015-10-07 13:02:24,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-10-07 13:02:24,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at BBDSK0201/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Please help what's that I could be missing

Comment: can you check the logs...

Comment: @madhu I included the datanode logs in the questions for your reference. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hadoop's datanode is not starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885330/hadoops-datanode-is-not-starting)

Answer (score 1):

1)Make sure the directory has right owner and permissions.

```
$ sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /home/vinod/.hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode
```

2) Delete the contents given in tmp directory. It is the parameter given for `hadoop.tmp.dir`

3) Format the namenode.

Start all the process again. Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks madhu, this is the best answer, which helped me after stucking with error WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/home/hduser/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode/ EPERM: Operation not permitted.